# Sniff wireless traffic between two machines via Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, kali-linux, sniffing, json

*Foreword: I am woefully inexperienced with this. As in, this is literally my first time encountering something like this. Please bear with me.*

Hello everyone,

The situation is as follows. We (as in, my company) are developing an application that will utilize the Ricoh Theta S camera and its API. The camera is connected via its hotspot to a phone, and it supports only that one connection. It communicates via HTTP on the IP address `192.168.1.1`, port `80`. Content type is `application/json`.

However, the settings we try to apply seem to be buggy and they're not exactly working as expected, so we'd like to use one laptop to sniff the communication between the camera and the phone application, and dump the JSON payloads associated with the packets.

I have installed Kali Linux as it comes with various useful tools, primarily Wireshark, out of the box. I already tried using `airmon-ng start wlan0` and then capturing on `wlan0mon` in monitor mode. While I was able to find and filter traffic on the SSID of the camera's hotspot, I couldn't locate any JSON in that communication.

I have the wpk2 password used to connect to the hotspot. I tried following [this article](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11), as well, but I'm still getting misc. information instead of "real" traffic.

Is it possible to monitor this traffic as a 3rd party and save the JSON payloads attached to it? I can't directly intercept this, again, as the camera needs a 1:1 connection (i.e., can be connected to only one host at a time).

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: maybe do some troubleshooting like try with a basic program that sends some packets then see if you see them in wireshark, then send some json, see if you see those. e.t.c.

Answer (score 0):

In monitor mode wireshark will be sniffing packets from other devices. So you have to filter those out or search through them. Also, in monitor mode it cannot be 100% guaranteed that all packets in the air will be captured.

What I would suggest is using a man in the middle attack. In that way all packets transferred is bound to go through your sniffer. Try using ettercap, it comes with kali linux. It will set up a man in the middle topology and then you can start sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

If the phone is running Android, I suggest you install tcpdump on it. You may output to a file in libpcap format and analyse it with wireshark for convenience.
I know this doesn't help with the third party sniffing problem, but is maybe an alternative solution to what you want to achieve.